# store/cache ajax sent data to avoid repeated request

Tags: ajax, performance

I developed a widget that offer a full blown archive search tool, where the user can select various options that are joined into an objects to be passed to WP_Query in an ajax action that returns the results data via JSON.

10 results are sent back to the page so pagination is needed. A new request is sent every time the page is turned. More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12200973/better-many-small-ajax-request-or-a-big-one-for-global-site-performance).

My question is: to decrease the request payload, I want that if the action is called after a page turn the information about the query is not sent but just the change page order is sent.

To achieve this i suppose the solution is to store the already sent query.

How is possible to do this?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attempting to answer this question directly: if the data you are returning is exactly the same each time, you can send cache control / expires headers with your AJAX response so that the browser knows not to request again for a while.

```
// ask the browser to cache this response, to reduce requests
$expires = 60 * 15;        // 15 minutes
header('Pragma: public');
header('Cache-Control: maxage=' . $expires);
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + $expires) . ' GMT');
```

But if you want different data each time, which it sounds like you do (via paging), then caching does nothing for you here. [This answer on your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12201804/911083) explains why you would be better off grabbing small chunks at a time.